# Acessar method do tipo String com reflection

Tags: java, reflexão, enums

Possuo a seguinte classe de enum:

```
public enum Teste {

    TESTE( 101, "Teste" ), 
    MUNDO( 601, "Mundo" ); 
    

    private final String descricao;
    private final int codigo;

    Teste( int codigo, String descricao ) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

}
```

Estou tentando acessar os atributos dos enums utilizando reflection:

```
String classe = "br.com.test.Teste";
Class<?> cls = Class.forName( classe );

Object[] listaEnum = cls.getEnumConstants();

for( Object enumsL : listaEnum ) {

        enumDto = new IndiceReajusteEnumDTO();
        enumDto.setId( enumsL.toString() );
        Method mtDescricao = cls.getDeclaredMethod( "getDescricao" );
        mtDescricao.setAccessible( true );
        String valorDescricao = ( String ) mtDescricao.invoke( cls.newInstance() );
        enumDto.setDescricao( valorDescricao );
        enumDto.setCodigo( cls.getMethod( "getCodigo" ).toGenericString() );            

        enumsArray.add( enumDto );
    }
```

Nessa linha `String valorDescricao = ( String ) mtDescricao.invoke( cls.newInstance() );`

ocorre a seguinte exceção:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: br.com.Teste.<init>()
 java.lang.InstantiationException: br.com.Teste
```

Caso necessário, segue o DTO:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class IndiceReajusteEnumDTO {

    private String id;
    private String descricao;
    private String codigo;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema estava aqui ao chamar o metodo invoke,
estava reiniciando a instância e na verdade precisava passar como parâmetro o meu objeto.

```
String valorDescricao = ( String ) mtDescricao.invoke( cls.newInstance() );
```

para

```
String valorDescricao = ( String ) mtDescricao.invoke( enumL );
```